# Bone creation script with bpy on blender

Tags: python, blender

I got big data arrays of bone's, which contains

`Bone Name > Parent Bone Name > Children Bone Name`

**Each of those bones has special coords such as:**

```
Quaternion(RotationsToParent[i]) # RotationsToParent / Quaternion  
Vector(TranslationToParent[i]) # TranslationToParent / Vector3  

Quaternion(RotationsToOrigin[i]) # RotationsToOrigin / Quaternion  
Vector(TranslationToOrigin[i]) # TranslationToOrigin / Vector3  

Quaternion(RotationsToLocal[i]) # RotationsToLocal / Quaternion  
Vector(TranslationToLocal[i]) # TranslationToLocal / Vector3
```

The datas from unknown extension file, but the datas enough to create something big!, only hint here is their variable names, and the BPY documentation doesnt explains much about bones, in documentation creation of Head/Tail for bones is declared, but no information i found about how to create/set Quaternion & Vector for bones,

Here's my script (works anormal) to place bone in right place

```
        import bpy 
        from bpy.props import *
        from mathutils import Vector, Quaternion
        
        armature = bpy.data.armatures.new("Armature")
        rig = bpy.data.objects.new("Armature", armature)

        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rig)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = rig
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

        BoneNames = [...]
        ChildBoneNames = [...] 
        ParentBoneNames = [...]  


        # Each bone contains those values
        RotationsToParent = [...] # Quaternion 
        TranslationToParent = [...] # Vector3 
        RotationsToOrigin = [...] # Quaternion  
        TranslationToOrigin = [...] # Vector3  
        RotationsToLocal = [...] # Quaternion 
        TranslationToLocal = [...] # Vector3 

        for i, BONE in enumerate(BoneNames):
            BoneArrIndex = i
            BoneName = BONE

            CurrentRTP = Quaternion(RotationsToParent[BoneArrIndex]) # RotationsToParent / Quaternion  
            CurrentTTP = Vector(TranslationToParent[BoneArrIndex]) # TranslationToParent / Vector3  

            CurrentRTO = Quaternion(RotationsToOrigin[BoneArrIndex]) # RotationsToOrigin / Quaternion  
            CurrentTTO = Vector(TranslationToOrigin[BoneArrIndex]) # TranslationToOrigin / Vector3   

            CurrentRTL = Quaternion(RotationsToLocal[BoneArrIndex]) # RotationsToLocal / Quaternion  
            CurrentTTL = Vector(TranslationToLocal[BoneArrIndex]) # TranslationToLocal / Vector3   

            # create new bone
            current_bone = armature.edit_bones.new(BoneName)
            print("@",BoneName)
            
            # first bone in chain
            if i == 0:
                print(i)
                # create bone at armature origin and set its length
                current_bone.head = [0, 0, 0]
                length = list(TranslationToParent[ BoneArrIndex + 1 ])[0]
                current_bone.tail = [0, 0, length]

                quat_armature_space = CurrentRTO
                current_bone.transform(quat_armature_space.to_matrix(), scale=True, roll=True)
                                
                # set position
                current_bone.translate(CurrentTTO)


                # save bone, its tail position (next bone will be moved to it) and quaternion rotation
                parent_bone = current_bone
                parent_bone_tail = current_bone.tail
                parent_bone_quat_armature_space = quat_armature_space
                
            # last bone in chain
            elif i == (len(BoneNames) - 1):

                # create bone at armature origin and set its length
                current_bone.head =  [0, 0, 0]
                current_bone.tail = [0, 0, 1]
                
                # rotate bone, around origin?
                # like matrices, quaternions can be multiplied to accumulate rotational values
                transform_quat = parent_bone_quat_armature_space @ CurrentRTO
                current_bone.transform(transform_quat.to_matrix(),  scale=True, roll=True)

                # set position, around origin?
                current_bone.translate(parent_bone_tail)

                ## connect
                current_bone.parent = parent_bone
                current_bone.use_connect = True
                
            else:
                # create bone at armature origin and set its length
                current_bone.head = [0, 0, 0]
                length = list(TranslationToParent[ BoneArrIndex + 1 ])[0]
                current_bone.tail = [0, 0, length]

                # rotate bone, around origin?
                # like matrices, quaternions can be multiplied to accumulate rotational values
                transform_quat = parent_bone_quat_armature_space @ CurrentRTO

                current_bone.transform(transform_quat.to_matrix(),  scale=True, roll=True)
                
                # set position, around origin?
                current_bone.translate(parent_bone_tail)
                
                # connect
               
                current_bone.parent = parent_bone
                current_bone.use_connect = True
                    
                # save bone, its tail position (next bone will be moved to it) and quaternion rotation
                parent_bone = current_bone
                parent_bone_tail = current_bone.tail
                parent_bone_quat_armature_space = transform_quat
```

So, i tried to switch every head/tail variables with other translation variables i declared on top, but didnt work, the results are anormal check the result:
[Anormal Bones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoSVz.png)

And yet i havent figured out whats wrong with my bone placer script, what could be wrong here?

Edit1:
After many hours of searching i've updated the bone creator script, and the results enlightened me a bit, **probably all those Quaternion/Vector values should be applied to bone from different axis**, heres new result that i got from new bone placer script, **all bones placed in same direction but on different lenghts**, only **RotationToOrigin & TranslateToOrigin coords applied** but how do i apply other unused quats/vectors values?

**Here** are unused cord values in the image below :
(RotationToLocale & TranslationToLocale & RotationToParent),

[image: Bones after update]

however each of **quat/vector coords probably has to be applied to each bone which is confused me.**